# Getting error in lockToPortrait() function in react-native-orientation library

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using **react-native-orientation** library to make my app only open in portrait mode.
Here is my code for that:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
} from 'react-native';
import AppContainer from './src/screens/Navigation';
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        Orientation.lockToPortrait();
    })

    return (
        <AppContainer />
    );
};


export default App;
```

I'm getting error in running this code.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For android you could set orientation android simply by adding this line to AndroidManifest.xml in MainActivity tag

```
    <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" //add this line for portrait lock
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

On ios do this after opening the xcode file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the React Native Orientation package in NPM is not up to date. For now, just fetch the code directly from the repo like:

```
npm install --save react-native-orientation@git+https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation.git
```

The current version at master should have lockToPortrait() working on Android and iOS granted native linking/installing is correct.